# .htaccess redirect to another domain without robots.txt

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains, and this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.old$
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.new/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

So this is full redirect from one site to another, which works as I need.
But how to do this redirect without file robots.txt? What rule I must add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an exception for `robots.txt`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain\.old$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!robots\.txt).*)$ http://domain.new/$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```